# Why doesn't my current directory show up in the path using pytest on Windows?

Tags: python, pytest

I have the following folder structure;

```
myapp\
  myapp\
     __init__.py
  tests\
     test_myapp.py
```

and my pwd is

```
C:\Users\wwerner\programming\myapp\
```

I have the following test setup:

```
import sys
import pprint

def test_cool():
    pprint.pprint(sys.path)
    assert False
```

That produces the following paths:

```
['C:\\Users\\wwerner\\programming\\myapp\\tests',
 'C:\\Users\\wwerner\\programming\\envs\\myapp\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python34.zip',
 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib',
 'C:\\Python34',
 'C:\\Users\\wwerner\\programming\\envs\\myapp',
 'C:\\Users\\wwerner\\programming\\envs\\myapp\\lib\\site-packages']
```

And when I try to `import myapp` I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'myapp'
```

So it looks like it's not adding the current directory to my path.

By changing my import line to look like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '.')
import myapp
```

I am then able to import `myapp` with no problems.

Why does my current directory not show up in the path when running pytest? Is my only workaround to insert `.` into the `sys.path`? (I'm using Python 3.4 if it matters)

Comment: Have you tried importing `myapp` before importing `pytest` (to make sure pytest is the problem here)? Try `import myapp` as the very first line in the script.

Comment: @SunnyNanda tried that, too. Still doesn't work.

Comment: _Why does my current directory not show up in the path when running pytest?_ Why should it? It's not a usual behavior for the current working directory to be in `sys.path`, except when working in the REPL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ahah!

After comparing the layout of my [cookiecutter repo](https://github.com/waynew/cookiecutter-pypackage/tree/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/tests), it turns out to be way more simple (and better) than that.

```
tests/
    __init__.py
    test_myapp.py
```

A simple addition of the `__init__.py` file to my test dir allows me to run `py.test` from my main directory.

Comment: Doing this was explicitly discouraged in the "good practices" section of the pytest docs. It only makes your package importable by accident. If you do it like this, you're somewhat obliged to use a src-based project layout. See https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/2297/ for all the details about why.

Comment: One of these days I should go back and figure out why in the world I needed to do that :) I suspect there's a much better way to do what I needed to do (like probably install my package in a virtualenv with `python -m pip install -e .` or something)

Comment: Yes, installing the package is the usual/recommended way. If you don't want to install it (eg you don't have any installer), then using python -m pytest instead of just pytest is the documented way to get the cwd present in sys.path. Should I add an answer? Nobody here mentioned it yet..

Comment: @wim an answer like that would be great for me, I encountered the same issue as Wayne Werner but i still dont understand why adding his solution to mine works and what's bad about it

Comment: @YevGuyduy OK, I've added a detailed answer which has a section at the end explaining why this solution appears to work, but is actually a bad idea. I know Wayne had good intentions but it's still wrong and I hate to see a wrong accepted answer..

Comment: thank you very much @win! i will take "hey looks like its working" over not working and i will take done right working over  the first one.  thanks again!

Comment: which solution is worse? adding a `_init__.py`? or modifying the sys.path in the test source?

Comment: @KansaiRobot Adding `__init__.py` in the test directory is certainly worse, because it doesn't work with the importlib import mode (which will be the default in future version of pytest). Testing against the installed code is best, but if you don't want to make an installable package for some reason then appending to `sys.path` from within the test code is fine. You can do this in `conftest.py` to make sure that it gets in before the code under test gets imported.

Answer (score 5):

#### Using an installable package

If you have an installable package (`setup.py` or `pyproject.toml` file with a build-system defined) then it's best to test against the installed code. Installing the code in a [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) will make import statements resolve correctly within that venv.

```
pip install --editable .
pytest
```

The simplest possible way to make the project shown in the question into an installable package would be by adding this `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="myapp",
    version="0.1",
    packages=["myapp"],
)
```

This will put the `myapp` code at `/path/to/myapp/.venv/lib/python3.XY/site-packages`, which is in the `sys.path` of the virtual environment. Now `myapp` can be imported from the `site-packages` dir, just as it would be for a user installation. *It is neither necessary nor desirable for the current working directory to be present on `sys.path` during test execution.*

#### Not using an installable package

The project shown in the question does not have any installer, so it can't be installed. It can still be tested by making sure the project root (i.e. the directory which contains both `myapp` and `tests` as subdirectories) is present on `sys.path`.

The best way to do this is to use `python -m pytest`, rather than invoking the bare `pytest` command. When you use `python -m pytest` it adds the current working directory to the start of `sys.path`. That's the normal Python behavior when executing a package as `__main__` (documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m)) and it's also a documented usage for pytest - see [*Invoking `pytest` versus `python -m pytest`*](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/pythonpath.html#invoking-pytest-versus-python-m-pytest).

#### Why does adding an `__init__.py` to the `tests` subdirectory (not) work?

The directory structure shown in the question is the "*Tests outside application code*" pattern, documented [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/goodpractices.html#tests-outside-application-code). This is also the directory structure I recommend, since it creates a clear distinction between library/application code and test code.

It's not recommended to add `__init__.py` files inside the test directories when using a "*Tests outside application code*" structure, since the test files aren't intended to be "packaged" (e.g. test files do not really need to import from other test files, and they do not need to be installed at all for end users of your package).

The reason adding a `myapp/__init__.py` actually allows `myapp` to be imported by `pytest` (as shown in [Wayne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21269155/674039)) is actually an *accident* due to the way test discovery appends `sys.path` during the test collection phase. This is described as "problematic" in the [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules)

> ... this introduces a subtle problem: in order to load the test modules from the `tests` directory, pytest prepends the root of the repository to `sys.path`, which adds the side-effect that now `mypkg` is also importable

They go on to strongly recommend using the [src-layout](https://hynek.me/articles/testing-packaging) if you intend to have `__init__.py` files inside test directories, to avoid this confusion of the import system.

But perhaps the best reason not to rely on this side-effect is that pytest collection actually can work in multiple modes (see [import modes](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/pythonpath.html#import-modes)), and Wayne's answer relies upon pytest using the "prepend" import mode. Prepend mode is currently the default, but the docs [mention](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/pythonpath.html#import-modes) that a future version will switch to using "importlib" mode by default:

> We intend to make `importlib` the default in future releases.

The accepted answer does not work with `pytest --import-mode=importlib` and so will stop working altogether at some stage.

Answer (score 0):

sys.path automatically has the script's directory in it, and not the current working directory.

I am guessing that your script in placed in `tests` directory. Based on this assumption, your code should look like this:

```
import sys
import os

ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(ROOT_DIR)

import myapp # Should work now
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the environment variable [`PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#envvar-PYTHONPATH).

In Windows:

```
set PYTHONPATH=.
py.test
```

In Unix:

```
PYTHONPATH=. py.test
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary because by default the current directory should be inserted in sys.path. Refer http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path

Comment: @SunnyNanda, It is not the current working directory that is inserted, but **the directory containing the script**.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I was earlier assuming the script to be present in the main directory itself. I added an answer with the assumption that the called script is placed in a child directory.