# How to run tests without installing package?

Tags: python, pytest

I have some Python package and some tests. The files are layed out following http://pytest.org/latest/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules

> Putting tests into an extra directory outside your actual application
>   code, useful if you have many functional tests or for other reasons
>   want to keep tests separate from actual application code (often a good
>   idea):
>
> ```
> setup.py   # your distutils/setuptools Python package metadata
> mypkg/
>     __init__.py
>     appmodule.py
> tests/
>         test_app.py
> ```

My problem is, when I run the tests `py.test`, I get an error

> ImportError: No module named 'mypkg'

I can solve this by installing the package `python setup.py install` but this means the tests run against the *installed* package, not the local one, which makes development very tedious. Whenever I make a change and want to run the tests, I need to reinstall, else I am testing the old code.

What can I do?

Comment: The link has changed to https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I know this question has been already closed, but a simple way I often use is to call `pytest` via `python -m`, from the root (the parent of the package).

```
$ python -m pytest tests
```

This works because `-m` option adds the current directory to the python path, and hence `mypkg` is detected as a local package (not as the installed).

See:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-through-python-m-pytest

Comment: Even if the user had run pytest from the root directory, then pytest would work isnt it?

Answer (score 18):

The normal approach for development is to use a virtualenv and use `pip install -e .` in the virtualenv (this is almost equivalent to `python setup.py develop`).  Now your source directory is used as installed package on sys.path.

There are of course a bunch of other ways to get your package on sys.path for testing, see [Ensuring py.test includes the application directory in sys.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971619/ensuring-py-test-includes-the-application-directory-in-sys-path) for a question with a more complete answer for this exact same problem.

Comment: Thanks sounds like I want `python setup.py develop`

Comment: @flub thanks for this, saved me some time, this is a great link for more understanding as well https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html

Answer (score 2):

On my side, while developing, I prefer to run tests from the IDE (using a runner extension) rather than using the command line. However, before pushing my code or prior to a release, I like to use the command line.

Here is a way to deal with this issue, allowing you to run tests from both the test runner used by your IDE and the command line.

My setup:

- **IDE**: Visual Studio Code
- **Testing**: pytest
- **Extension (test runner)**: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LittleFoxTeam.vscode-python-test-adapter
- **Work directory structure** (my solution should be easily adaptable to your context):

  ```
  project_folder/

      src/
          mypkg/
              __init__.py
              appmodule.py
      tests/
           mypkg/
              appmodule_test.py
      pytest.ini           <- Use so pytest can locate pkgs from ./src 
      .env                 <- Use so VsCode and its extention can locate pkgs from ./src
  ```
- **.env**:

  ```
   PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH};./src;"
  ```
- **pytest.ini (tried with pytest 7.1.2)**:

  ```
   [pytest]
   pythonpath = . src
  ```
- **./src/mypkg/appmodule.py**:

  ```
   def i_hate_configuring_python():
       return "Finally..."
  ```
- **./tests/mypkg/appmodule_test.py**:

  ```
  from mypkg import app_module


  def test_demo(): 
      print(app_module.i_hate_configuring_python())
  ```

This should do the trick

Answer (score -1):

Import the package using `from .. import mypkg`. For this to work you will need to add (empty) `__init__.py` files to the tests directory and the containing directory. `py.test` should take care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks that might well work but the same guide cautions "avoid `__init__.py` files in your test directories" so I'm wary of doing that http://pytest.org/latest/goodpractises.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules

Comment: This wouldn't work in Python 3 as stated by @woody1193 because Python considers test.py as as the top level module therefore using a relative import as you suggested would give you an error ```ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package```

Comment: @ApichartThanomkiet the question is from 2014 and does not specify python 3. The lack of backwards compatibility broke a lot of import related code and answers.