# How to run seperate folder of pytests in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a pytests for my code in VSCode from a separate folder, but I keep getting the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

My basic file structure is:

```
Root
|
|- src
| |- file1.py
|
|- tests
| |- test_file.py
```

My code in test_file.py is:

```
from src import file1
```

I saw [How to run tests without installing package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984973/how-to-run-tests-without-installing-package) and all of the millions of other import questions but I still can't figure it out. I've also tried

```
from ..src import file1
```

but then I get an *ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package*

How do I use imports in this way to run tests on my code?

Comment: what command are you using to run your tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the `PYTHONPATH` to avoid this problem. You can refer to the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable).

> An example of when to use PYTHONPATH would be if you have source code
> in a src folder and tests in a tests folder. When running tests,
> however, those tests can't normally access modules in src unless you
> hard-code relative paths.
>
> To solve this problem, you could add the path to src to PYTHONPATH by
> creating an .env file within your VS Code workspace.
>
> PYTHONPATH=src Then set python.envFile in your settings.json file to
> point to the .env file you just created. For example, if the .env file
> was in your workspace root, your settings.json would be set as shown:
>
> "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"

And the Test is not routed through the terminal, so setting the `terminal.integrated.env.*` will not work.

Comment: @Ethan Shapiro Have you solved the problem? if this is helpful, could you accept this answer? thanks, and have a good day : ).

Comment: Yes! This is a great answer. I did not realize that creating an environment was the usual way to do these things. Would this allow me to test using the built in testing portion of VScode?