# ModuleNotFound error when importing modules for pytest

Tags: python, pytest, python-import

I'm trying to run pytest on some functions I've written in Airflow. I'm using Python 3.8, btw.

The folder structure is

```
airflow
   -- dags
       -- includes
           -- common
               -- functions.py
   -- tests
       -- test_functions.py
```

I tried `from includes.common.functions import functionA, functionB`, but kept getting the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'functions'`.

If I try `from dags.includes.common.functions import functionA, functionB`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dags'`.

I've tried `python -m pytest tests` in the `airflow` folder, same import error.

I'm not very familiar with importing modules, and would appreciate any help in how to solve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following to my script, and was able to run `pytest` without the import errors.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../dags/')

from includes.common.functions import functionA, functionB
```

I was also able to run it without any `__init__.py` in any of the folders.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49605830/modulenotfounderror-issue-for-pytest?rq=1) helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.` to go one directory up to search for files. Use this import statement inside `test_functions.py`:

```
from ..dags.includes.common.functions import functionA, functionB
```

Also, every folder needs an empty `__init.py__` file. Create them for the folders airflow, dags, includes, common and tests.

Comment: When I tried to run `pytest test_functions.py` in the `tests` folder, I get the error message `from ..dags.includes.common.functions import functionA, functionB   ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: Could you try replacing `..` with a single `.` instead and share the results

Comment: I currently have empty `__init__.py` in `tests` and `common`, and I'm running `pytest test_functions.py` in the `tests` folder. With `..`, I get the `attempted relative import beyond top-level package` error. With `.`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests.dags'`.

Comment: If I remove the `__init__.py` files, with both `..` and `.`, I get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: Good that you mention `__init__.py`, please add it to every directory.

Comment: I should add `__init__.py` even in `includes` and `common` even though there are no `.py` files in them?

Comment: Yes, you should. I believe they are used to mark mark directories.

Comment: I've added `__init__.py` to every subfolder, but still get a `attempted relative import beyond top-level package` with `..`. If this helps, I have `__name__=tests.test_functions      | __package__=tests`.